# Opening a GPS location from an SMS

Tags: sms, gps

How can I format an SMS in order to send the GPS location? The recipient should be able to tap the text and open the coordinates with their favorite location software (e.g., Google Maps).

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know there is no standard for sending coordinates (such as a URI scheme like `gps://[latitude],[longitude]`), but you could use direct links to Google Maps. The format is `https://maps.google.com/maps?q=[latitude],[longitude]`. This enables most phones to create a link from the text, and the coordinates are easily available for copy/pasting to other apps as well.

Comment: I believe it's even better to remove the first `maps.` to get it shorter: `https://google.com/maps?q=`